# Call function before calling template in Angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'd like to call a function passing it one of the scope variables below, but I'm getting the error:

> ReferenceError: activityLog is not defined

Just wondering if what I'm trying to do here is possible? My function is getting called OK, but I want to be able to pass it the scope variable as well.

```
function (angular, jQuery, oModule) {
    'use strict';

    oModule.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                activityLog: '@',
            },
            // Why can't I pass activityLog here?
            // ReferenceError: activityLog is not defined
            template: generateDetails(activityLog)
        };
    });

    function generateDetails(oActivityLog) {

    }
```

Comment: You can't pass it there. You're obviously trying to do something that should be done differently in Angular. Please, explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: @estus The generateDetails function will have a lot of JavaScript logic in it based on whats on the activityLog, I need to run that logic to generate the contents of the template.

Comment: This approach is not correct. Bindings are not available at the time when directive template is created. If you have problems with implementing it, please, explain what exactly should be done here, so the appropriate question could be given.

Comment: What is the correct approach then for what I'm trying to do: Invoking a directive, passing it a variable, which the directive uses to generate a string to place in the HTML? Where should the JavaScript logic go if not in the directive?

Comment: It is jQuery-ish approach, which is strongly discouraged in Angular. Any way, t should be done in link function, as the answer suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the `activityLog` scope in link function. Template is for you to have html template if there is.

```
function (angular, jQuery, oModule) {
    'use strict';

    oModule.directive('myDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                activityLog: '@',
            },
            link:function(scope, element, attr) {
                generateDetails(scope.activityLog);
            },
            template: '<div>123</div>' //html template here if needed
        };
    });

    function generateDetails(oActivityLog) {

    }
}
```